# css selector for elements without a class

Tags: css-selectors

```
<th style="position: relative; top: 0px;">
    <div style="width: 48.003906px;" data-lngst="nullpx" data-ndx="2">123</div></th>
<th id="" class="abc_naem" nowrap="" style="position: relative; top: 0px;">
    <div style="width: 44.003906px;" data-lngst="nullpx" data-ndx="4">...</div>
<th style="position: relative; top: 0px;">
    <div style="width: 48.003906px;" data-lngst="nullpx" data-ndx="5">123</div></th>
<th id="" class="abc_phase" nowrap="" style="position: relative; top: 0px;">
    <div style="width: 44.003906px;" data-lngst="nullpx" data-ndx="3">...</div>
```

how do I select all 'th' element using css selectors that do not have a classname? All the 'th' elements have exactly the same attributes except classname and I need the ones without it. I tried `th[classname='']` and that does not do the trick. I tried all the css selection options like 'no-child' etc, still it always returns all `th` elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your HTML is properly formed, you can use [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) with the attribute selector [`[]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). Ex `th:not([class])`

Example:

```css
th:not([class]) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th style="position: relative; top: 0px;">
      <div style="width: 48.003906px;" data-lngst="nullpx" data-ndx="2">123</div>
    </th>
    <th id="" class="abc_naem" nowrap="" style="position: relative; top: 0px;">
      <div style="width: 44.003906px;" data-lngst="nullpx" data-ndx="4">123</div>
      <th style="position: relative; top: 0px;">
        <div style="width: 48.003906px;" data-lngst="nullpx" data-ndx="5">123</div>
      </th>
      <th id="" class="abc_phase" nowrap="" style="position: relative; top: 0px;">
        <div style="width: 44.003906px;" data-lngst="nullpx" data-ndx="3">123</div>
      </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks so ,much!!! I was trying`th:not(class)` and with your example, i realized, it has to be `th:not([class])`